# call ruby through jsp

Tags: ruby, jsp

I have a ruby program on my machine.

I want call it over the web.

I have built a jsp page for this and have made a call:

```
<%
    Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
    Process proc = rt.exec("ruby somepathtoruby.rb");
%>
```

Doesn't seem to be working properly though.

Can anyone help me out here?

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't seem to be working?  What do you want it to do?  Do you see the output of executing the ruby script in your logs?

Comment: The ruby file writes some things to the console. I wanted the JSP to read this console and put it on the web page. I couldn't figure a way to read the console. 
So, now the ruby program writes to a file and jsp reads the file through ajax and outputs it on the page. 
If any one knows how to read the ruby console directly, that will be of help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you can capture the output of the Ruby program the same way you would capture the output of any other separate process you launch from Java

[This page](http://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips/java.io/how-to-capture-the-output-of-an-external-program.html) shows how to do it for a standalone Java application.  You should be able to work it into a scriptlet in your JSP.

Comment: thanks. I ended up doing every operation through ajax. but that helped.